# How to remove a div present inside a div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

I'm trying to remove all the divs present with `class='characterCard'`, inside another div with `class='childContainer'`, when a button is pressed.
I've tried `.remove()` and `removeChild()` as well, but it doesn't work. Instead when using `.removeChild()`, I get the following error:
**Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.**

The Character cards are placed inside the childContainers, so the parent element is the `childDiv`

```js
let childDiv = document.querySelector('.childContainer');
let charDiv = document.querySelector('.characterCard');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  childDiv.removeChild(charDiv);
})
```

Comment: I think you just need to switch it to `charDiv.removeChild(childDiv)`

Answer (score 0):

Call `remove` on the child:

```js
let childDiv = document.querySelector('.childContainer');
let charDiv = document.querySelector('.characterCard');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  charDiv.remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are (likely) more than one `.characterCard` divs, you need to loop though all matching elements inside of `.childDiv` and remove one by one.

```
childDiv.querySelectorAll('.characterCard').forEach(el => el.remove())
```

```js
let childDiv = document.querySelector('.childContainer');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  childDiv.querySelectorAll('.characterCard').forEach(el => el.remove())
})
```